# Sending Player Alias (Game Center) via struct with ARC

Tags: ios, struct, automatic-ref-counting, game-center, multiplayer

What is the best approach for sending the local player's alias (or any text for that matter) to another device, since I can't put an NSString in my struct because of ARC/pointers?

So far, I've tried converting to & from a char array, using the __unsafe_unretained- option and trying to create a class to put the text in.  Though all three of these attempts worked through compiling, they crashed the device (simulator keeps running but no alias displays.)

Is sending text in multiplayer games really difficult when using ARC?  The issues I'm facing are most likely a result of the fact that I am not very experienced at programming... so if anyone could point me in the right direction or provide me with some snips of code, I'd really appreciate it.

Comment: Follow up:  I'm currently just pulling the alias' from Game Center.  I've spent days trying to figure out how to send text through the struct with ARC.  If anyone knows of an easy way, please let me know.

Answer (score 1):

You can easily encode and decode strings to NSData objects and send them over Game Center.

To encode: use this method on a string

```
- (NSData *)dataUsingEncoding:(NSStringEncoding)encoding
```

With encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding

This will return a NSData object

To decode;

```
NSString *dataString = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:data encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
```

Edit:

Essentially you'll never have to send player aliases explicitly. There are 2 cases:

1: GKTurnBasedMatch

If you're using this, then here's how to get a list of all of the aliases (including yours)

```
NSMutableArray *playerIds = [NSMutableArray arrayWithCapacity:match.participants.count];

for (GKTurnBasedParticipant *part in match.participants) {

if([participant.playerID isKindOfClass:[NSString class]]){
                [playerIds addObject:part.playerID];
            }
 } //at this point you have an array full of playerID strings, next you call this:

[GKPlayer loadPlayersForIdentifiers:(NSArray *)playerIds withCompletionHandler:(void (^)      (NSArray *players, NSError *error))completionHandler {

for (GKPlayer *playa in players) {

NSLog(@"%@",playa.alias); // here i'm just logging the aliases but you can do whatever..
}


}];
```

2.GKMatch : this case is much easier since your GKMatch has already playerIDs array, same as before:

```
[GKPlayer loadPlayersForIdentifiers:(NSArray *) match.playerIDs withCompletionHandler:(void (^)(NSArray *players, NSError *error))completionHandler {

//again you get the array players full of GKPlayer objects , simply pull the alias you want

}];
```